# Даны действительное число х вычислить с точностью до е c#?

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста с написанием программы: Даны действительное число х вычислить с точностью до е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это само задание, программа, которую написал:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, s = 0, y = 1, n = 0;
            double e;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите х");
            x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            e = 0.0001;
            while ((Math.Abs(y)) >= e)
            {
                s = s + y;
                n = n + 1;
                y = -y * x * x / ((2 * n - 1) * (2 * n));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Cos(x));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Выдает на данный момент такой ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть должно выводиться два числа одинаковых до 10 тысячных, остальное может быть разное, никак не могу понять в чем может быть ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int n = 0;
 double e, x, s = 0.0, y = 1.0;
```

решит проблему.

Comment: спасибо большое, очень сильно помогли!